# Copy all files from one directory and subdirectories into single location

Tags: ant

Here is my code for copying all .txt files from one location to other:

```
<copy todir="../new/dir">
    <fileset dir="C:/build/build">
        <include name="**/*.txt"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Altough it is working fine, it is copying files correctly but the problem is that it is maintainig the directory structure for non-empty directories at destination also, I want all the files under "C:/build/build" and its sub-directories shoul

Comment: I think you were about to finish saying

Answer (score 11):

From what you've written maybe you want to flatten the files?

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

```
<copy todir="../new/dir" flatten="true">
    <fileset dir="C:/build/build">
        <include name="**/*.txt"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Thanks Working fine....Just missed out Flatten