# Remove fileset directories from Ant war lib

Tags: ant

Is there a simple way to use Ant [`<mappedresources>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) to flatten directories in a `<fileset>` into a `<war>` `<lib>`. For example:

```
<fileset id="xx.lib" dir="${base.lib.path}">
    <include name="library1/library1.jar"/>
    <include name="library2/library2.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

So that the jars are in WEB-INF/lib without their "library1"/"library2" paths.

I have read the above link and several related questions here on SO, but I can't envision the mechanism to do exactly what I'm describing, for just one of several `<lib>` elements.

Comment: This answer may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560368/copy-all-files-from-one-directory-and-subdirectories-into-single-location

Comment: If only I could `flatten` without having to do a `copy`...